# AdMob house ads mediation on Android

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am trying to include some house ads with my normal AdMob ads. But whenever I set up a campaign, it immediately overwhelms the normal ads. The only way I can restore them is to delete the campaign altogether. I have tried various mediation settings but to no avail. Ideally I would like the campaign the be displayed about 5% of the time, but at the moment it is being displayed 100% of the time. What are the correct settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new publisher ID.
2. Create a House Ad campaign that fully allocates traffic - assign campaign to newly created publisher ID.
3. On your mediation placement, configure "AdMob Network" with your regular publisher ID.
4. On your mediation placement, configure "AdMob House Ads" with this newly created publisher ID configured to serve house ads every time.
5. Allocate your mediation placement by percentages.  Assign 95% to the AdMob network, and 5% to AdMob house ads.

UPDATE:

Percentage allocation is no longer available on AdMob. If the exact percentage isn't important to you, you can but house ads behind other networks in your mediation flow, and house ads will show any time you fail to get an ad from any of your other configured networks.

If you really really want to achieve percentages, you can write a AdMob custom event that randomly generates a number and decides whether to request a house ad or fail immediately and move on to that network. There is an example of this [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/examples/custom-events/src/com/google/example/ads/customevents/impl/PercentageHouseAds.java?repo=examples-android). Following that example, the steps would be altered to the following:

1. Same as above
2. Same as above
3. Put the sample class into your application, adjusting package as necessary
4. On your mediation placement, choose "Add custom Event" with the settings:

> Label: Percentage House Ad
>
> Class Name: com.google.example.ads.customevents.impl.PercentageHousAds (replace with your fully qualified class name)
>
> Parameter: {"publisherId": "YOUR_HOUSE_ADS_PUBLISHER_ID", "percentage": 5}

5.Make your custom event have the highest eCPM out of all your networks, so the custom event always gets requested first.

Comment: "As of 20 May 2013, percentage allocation for mediation placements has been deprecated. Existing mediation placements using percentage allocation will continue to operate, but you can no longer set percentage allocation for a new placement." https://support.google.com/admob/faq/2994346?hl=en-GB#2994360

Comment: I'm wandering whether it is a Google policy to make everything more and more difficult an unintuitive to use by the day. The whole thing does not make sense.

Comment: The motivation behind the change is to help developers maximize your revenue. When ordering networks, you should always want to request an ad from the network that pays the most first. Percentage allocation only enables you to not choose the best network any time. As for house ads, the most popular use case is to show them when there is no other ad to show (backfill them after all other networks), since you would otherwise not make any revenue off that request anyways. But if you have a special use case, there is still this workaround.